# Regex for phone number validation

Tags: ruby, regex

I have to find in string a phone number with conditions:

- Start with `0`
- with `10` or `11` number `0`-`9`
- with maximum 2 character `"-"` (Not at start or end)

Example: `01234567890`, `01-234567890`, `03-1234-12345`. 
My regex, but it not work:

```
/\d+{10,11}|(\d+\-\d+){11,12}|(\d+\-\d+\-\d+){12,13}/
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show what you did to attack the problem (besides ask strangers to do it for you for free). We will be happy to work with you to remove the problem you have in your code or way of thinking, but you need to demonstrate some code (or thinking) first.

Comment: I tried to using this regex but it not work:
/(\d+){10,11}|(\d+-\d+){11,12}|(\d+-\d+-\d+){12,13}/

Comment: Regex for what? One that matches a string that includes such pattern? One that excludes such string? One that extracts such pattern from a string?

Comment: `01-234567890` and `03-1234-12345` are 12 and 13 characters, respectively.

Comment: Just to make sure, `0123456789-` satisfies your pattern, right?

Comment: My regex but it not work:
   /\d+{10,11}|(\d+\-\d+){11,12}|(\d+\-\d+\-\d+){12,13}/

Comment: What about `012345--6789`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit tricky. First, your regexp kind of has the right idea. Given that the length changes with number of dashes, we need to check each case separately. (There might be a better way, but I can't think of one.) However, `(\d+-\d+){11,12}` does not mean "length being 11-12", but "11-12 repetitions of `\d+-\d+`, giving you way more than 11-12 characters. Even if it were correct, because of the order of the disjunction, you would not be able to match `0123456789-1`, because 10 digits would be found first, and ten digits followed by dash and another digit would not even be checked.

If you were trying to validate the whole string, it would have been easier, as you can use anchors `^` and `$` to find the end. Without it, it is a little trickier:

```
(?=[\d-]{13,14}(?![\d-]))0\d+-\d+-\d+(?![\d-])|(?=[\d-]{12,13}(?!-|\d))0\d+-\d+(?![\d-])|\d{10,11}
```

The first part, `(?=[\d-]{13,14}(?![\d-]))0\d+-\d+-\d+(?![\d-])`, checks for the two-dash pattern. `(?=[\d-]{13,14}(?![\d-]))` checks whether you have 13-14 digit-or-dash characters after which you *don't* have a digit nor a dash. After making sure there is such a region, we make sure there are exactly two dashes in between digits (and making sure the whole thing is, again, not followed by a digit-or-dash - this anchor synchronises the condition in our lookahead and in the main pattern).

The second part, `(?=[\d-]{12,13}(?!-|\d))0\d+-\d+(?![\d-])`, is analogous, checking for one-dash matches. The third part, `\d{10,11}`, is trivially simple, and finds no-dash matches.

All of this is under the assumption that `sawa`'s needling is on-point: that `0123456789-` is not a match. If it is, you will need to change some plusses into stars.

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/rZwPe2VgGQ)

EDIT: The Rubular pattern still has the wrong `\d{11,12}` for the dashless case, can't be bothered to generate another Rubular :P

EDIT2: Thought of a better way.

```
(?=(?:\d-?){10,11}(?![\d-]))\d+(-\d+){0,2}(?![\d-])
```

Make sure there's 10-11 digits, and make sure there's 0-2 dashes. The anchor idea is the same as in the previous one.

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/rZwPe2VgGQ).

Comment: Thank you @Amadan for your answer.
About last pattern `|\d{11,12}`, it should be `|0\d{10,11}`, then your regex work fine. Thank you.